# How do I install multiple architecture versions of a single package using synaptic?

Tags: apt, dependencies, synaptic, cross-compilation

I am trying to cross compile a program that uses GTK3. The host machine is x86_64 running Ubuntu 22.04. The target machine is arm64 or aarch64 running Debian (Bookworm). I have setup the cross-compilation toolchain with crosstools-ng.

I ran this command:

```
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` test_window.c -o test_window_cross `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

But I got this response:

```
In file included from /home/user/x-tools/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/features.h:527,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /home/user/x-tools/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/limits.h:26,
                 from /home/user/x-tools/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/13.2.0/include/limits.h:205,
                 from /home/user/x-tools/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/13.2.0/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /home/user/x-tools/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/gcc/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/13.2.0/include/limits.h:34,
                 from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:11,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkconfig.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from test_window.c:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h:7:11: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
    7 | # include <gnu/stubs-32.h>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I figured that this is happening because the gtk packages for arm64 are not on my computer. So I ran the following command to install the arm64 version of the gtk package(libgtk-3-dev) using apt.

```
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev:arm64
```

I got this response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 : Breaks: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:arm64 (< 2.40.0+dfsg-6~) but 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:arm64 : Depends: libc6:arm64 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
                            Depends: libglib2.0-0:arm64 (>= 2.48.0) but it is not installable
                            Depends: libjpeg8:arm64 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libpng16-16:arm64 (>= 1.6.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libtiff5:arm64 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libx11-6:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:arm64 (= 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.4)
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin:arm64 : Depends: libc6:arm64 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libglib2.0-0:arm64 (>= 2.48.0) but it is not installable
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:arm64 : Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:arm64 (= 2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.4) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libglib2.0-dev:arm64 (>= 2.37.6) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libx11-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libpng-dev:arm64 (>= 1.6) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libpng-dev:arm64 (< 1.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk-3-common : Breaks: libgtk-3-dev:arm64 (< 3.24.30-3~) but 3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 libgtk-3-dev:arm64 : Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0:arm64 (= 3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libatk1.0-dev:arm64 (>= 2.15.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libcairo2-dev:arm64 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libepoxy-dev:arm64 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libfontconfig1-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libfribidi-dev:arm64 (>= 0.19.7) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libglib2.0-dev:arm64 (>= 2.57.2) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpango1.0-dev:arm64 (>= 1.41) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libwayland-dev:arm64 (>= 1.9.91) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libx11-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libxcomposite-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libxcursor-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libxdamage-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libxext-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libxfixes-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libxi-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libxinerama-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libxkbcommon-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libxrandr-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend:arm64 but it is not installable or
                               gsettings-backend:arm64
                      Depends: libgtk-3-0:arm64 (= 3.24.20-0ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Then I went [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752214/installing-libgtk-3-dev-unmet-dependencies) and I got the idea to use synaptic manager. I installed synaptic manager and I tried installing the arm64 versions of the gtk packages. I got the following errors in the screenshot. (Note: I used the GUI version of synaptic)
[Screenshot showing the different architectures available for gtk packages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aziG1.png)

[Screenshot showing the response of synaptic if I attempt to install libgtk-3-dev:arm64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zkn7.png)

I have the following questions:

1. Is it impossible to have different architecture versions of the same package on a computer? If it isn't, how do I go about resolving the problem indicated in the screenshots?
2. Does installing the arm64 version of the gtk package automatically resolve the errors encountered during cross-compilation? If it doesn't do this automatically, how do I resolve it?

I look forward to your kind, positive and swift responses.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is possible to have different arch versions of the same package...

u can try this after making a backup of */etc/apt/sources.list* and */var/lib/dpkg/status* files.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f

$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

to resolve the dependencies issue and try again.
if this message appears after the last command, u can easly install your arch version of the pkg

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 0 not upgraded.
```

2. try 1. step and see what happens... first of all, step by step....

Comment: Thanks. I tried the steps, but they did not work. I got this response instead:<pre>Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
</pre>